# using arduino inestead arbotix for controll motors

Tags: dynamixel

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i want using arduino for control dc motor   . What steps are needed  ??
what change i need to use codes in  [ROS by Example Vol2 book](http://wiki.ros.org/Books/ROSbyExampleVol2) . i want using arduino inestead  arbotix controller  to send command to DC motors.
in book used [arbotix](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://wiki.ros.org/arbotix_python) package . like [this](https://github.com/pirobot/rbx2/blob/indigo-devel/rbx2_bringup/launch/pi_robot_with_gripper.launch) example(please look at line 14) . i have to change this package??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274104/using-arduino-inestead-arbotix-for-controll-motors/) by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 217 on 2017-10-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-26**:
If you don't want to change any code then this is not a ROS question I believe.

In general:

1. get a controller & amps that are compatible with your motors
2. find / write node with a similar enough ROS API as the dynamixel drivers
3. update the launch files

**Comment by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on 2017-10-26**:
can i change [this code](https://github.com/vanadiumlabs/arbotix_ros/blob/indigo-devel/arbotix_firmware/src/ros.ino) and upload on arduino ??

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-26**:
I have no idea. I don't use dynamixels, nor any of the `arbotix` packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is an explanation of how you could have an arduino control your motors in a general way:

Components required:

- An arduino with code that can control your motor
- A computer running ROS and a node that publishes data to a topic, such as an integer that corresponds to a motor value that you would like to use as a throttle value for your motor

If you have those two things you can modify the arduino code by adding ROS functionality to it. Do the first of these 3 tutorials: http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup

- [Arduino IDE Setup](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup)
- [Hello World (example publisher)](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Hello%20World)
- [Blink (example subscriber)](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Blink)

With these examples you will gain the knoweledge to allow you to send AND receive data to/from your arduino. With this knoweldge you can have your arduino serve a motor controller, by sending it throttle values and having it convert those throttle values to whatever signals are required to control your motors. Easy peazy lemon squeezy!

---

Originally posted by [psammut](https://answers.ros.org/users/31213/psammut/) with karma: 258 on 2017-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on 2017-10-27**:
thanks . in book used [arbotix](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://wiki.ros.org/arbotix_python) package  . like [this](https://github.com/pirobot/rbx2/blob/indigo-devel/rbx2_bringup/launch/pi_robot_with_gripper.launch) example . i shoud to change this package??

**Comment by [psammut](https://answers.ros.org/users/31213/psammut/) on 2017-10-27**:
You should create your own package and your own node to interface with the arduino. First get the arduino to control your motors, then create a package and node to talk to the arduino.

**Comment by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on 2017-10-27**:
i want to run [this](https://github.com/pirobot/rbx2/blob/indigo-devel/rbx2_arm_nav/scripts/moveit_ik_demo.py)  example . what data is send to serial port ?? can i write program in arduino to get these data from serial port and manage dc motors?